# JavaFx setOnCloseRequest & File check wait

Tags: java, javafx

I have two windows. The first one is been launched if a property file doesn't exist. The second is ( I want it to be) opened if the file already exists OR when the user click the button which creates the file. Here is the code....

```
try {
        if(f.exists()) {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            prop.load(input);
        }

        if(f.exists() && prop.getProperty("name") != null){
            primaryStage.show();
        }else if(prop.getProperty("name") == null || !f.exists()){

            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();

                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("summ.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = loader.load();

                stage.setTitle("temp");
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));

                stage.showAndWait();

                summController summController = loader.getController();
                String name = summController.getName();
                stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{

                    if(prop.getProperty("name") != null || f.exists()) {
                        primaryStage.show();
                    }
                });
```

Before, instead of the setOnCloseRequest, I just had "primaryStage.show();" but this would open the second window no matter what, after closing the first one. So, it would open if I press the button, but also if I clicked the X in the top corner. I don't want it to be. I tried the setOnCloseRequest to check if the user set his name before he quit (basicly if he pressed the button to save) this way, it doesn't show when I close with the X but also doesn't open if the button is pressed. I want it to open when the button is pressed but not the X. I 'think' that the problem might be that when the user press the button, it "instantly" check for the file but it isn't created yet....

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to close the window, you should consume the close request event:

```
if(prop.getProperty("name") != null || f.exists()) {
    primaryStage.show();
} else {
    e.consume();
}
```